# Bind to a column in DataGrid happens only after a line break

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a `WPF DataGrid` that his columns bind to variables in ObservableCollection that sits on ViewModel,

Here's the code:

```
 <DataGrid  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedXIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding XViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding XList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
XList= ObservableCollection<X>

Class X = (Name- Implement notify property changed)
```

When I edit a column the changes are received to viewmodel only by a line break (instead of leaving the state of editing) Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, here is the code:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Binding="{Binding Name,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```